# How to use background tasks with Starlette when there's no background object?

Tags: starlette, ariadne-graphql

I'm hoping to avoid any use of Celery at the moment. In Starlette's docs they give two ways to add background tasks:

Via Graphene: https://www.starlette.io/graphql/

```py
class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    user_agent = graphene.String()

    def resolve_user_agent(self, info):
        """
        Return the User-Agent of the incoming request.
        """
        user_agent = request.headers.get("User-Agent", "<unknown>")
        background = info.context["background"]
        background.add_task(log_user_agent, user_agent=user_agent)
        return user_agent
```

Via a JSON response: https://www.starlette.io/background/

```py
async def signup(request):
    data = await request.json()
    username = data['username']
    email = data['email']
    task = BackgroundTask(send_welcome_email, to_address=email)
    message = {'status': 'Signup successful'}
    return JSONResponse(message, background=task)
```

Does anyone know of a way to add tasks to Starlette's background with Ariadne? I am unable to return a JSONResponse in my resolver, and I do not have access to a info.context["background"]. The only thing I have attached to my context is my request object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above which is marked as a solution does not work for me since BackgroundTask does not work properly when you use a middleware that subclasses BaseHTTPMiddleware see here:

https://github.com/encode/starlette/issues/919

In my case basically the task is not ran in the background and it is awaited to be completed, also I am not using Ariadne, but this should let you do the job and run a task in the background

Edit:
This worked for me.

```
executor = ProcessPoolExecutor()

main.executor.submit(
bg_process_funcs,
export_file_format,
export_headers,
data,
alert_type,
floor_subtitle,
date_subtitle,
pref_datetime,
pref_timezone,
export_file_name,
export_limit,)

executor.shutdown()
logger.info("Process Pool Shutdown")
```

Comment: Added your comment as the accepted one. My response is very old. I'll leave it up just in case it helps someone. Thank you for your contribution.

Answer (score 2):

**Solved!**

Starlette Middleware:

```py
class BackgroundTaskMiddleware(BaseHTTPMiddleware):
    async def dispatch(
            self, request: Request, call_next: RequestResponseEndpoint
    ) -> Response:
        request.state.background = None
        response = await call_next(request)
        if request.state.background:
            response.background = request.state.background
        return response
```

Ariadne Resolver:

```py
@query.field("getUser")
@check_authentication
async def resolve_get_user(user, obj, info):
    task = BackgroundTasks()
    task.add_task(test_func)
    task.add_task(testing_func_two, "I work now")
    request = info.context["request"]
    request.state.background = task
    return True


async def test_func():
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    print("once!!")


async def testing_func_two(message: str):
    print(message)
```

The functions still execute synchronously, but because they're background tasks I'm not too worried.

[More discussion here.](https://spectrum.chat/ariadne/general/how-to-use-background-tasks-with-starlette~74d56970-5676-4484-8586-a9384e5f4d56)